# Bash Script can run php script manually but cannot work in Cron

Tags: bash, cron, php-5.6

I have a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

log_file=/home/michael/bash/test.log

checkalive=checkalive.php

#declare
needRestart=0

#Check checkalive.php

is_checkalive=`ps aux | grep -v grep| grep -v "$0" | grep $checkalive| wc -l | awk '{print $1}'`

if [ $is_checkalive != "0" ] ;
then

    checkaliveId=$(ps -ef | grep $checkalive | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ printf $2 }')

    echo "Service $checkalive is running. $checkaliveId"

else

    echo "$checkalive OFF"
    needRestart=1

fi

#NEED needRestart

if [ $needRestart == "1" ];
then
    #START SERVICE
    echo "Restarting services..."

    /usr/bin/php5.6 /home/michael/bash/$checkalive >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    echo "$checkalive..."
    echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` " Start /home/michael/bash/$checkalive" >> $log_file
fi
```

I can run it manually but when I try to run it in Cron, it doesn't work for some reasons. Apparently the command:

```
/usr/bin/php5.6 /home/michael/bash/$checkalive >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

does not work.

All of file permissions are already set to executable. Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: can you provide some logs ? Is your cron triggering the job ? Is your job failing ?

Comment: Did you give `$checkalive` in the cron command? Thats not right. You need to set whatever value you are getting in bash script by yourself. What is the script file name?

Comment: Discarding standard error is extremely misdirected. You will want to take out the `>/dev/null` or redirect to a file instead, at least until you have sorted out your problem. Probably PHP tells you exactly why it won't run.

Comment: @user2599522 the cron log didn't say anything useful for debugging this problem

Comment: @ViKiG, I already found the problem. It's because of environment variables difference. But your answers was leading me to check it. So thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have run into one of cron's most common mistakes, trying to use it like an arbitrary shell script. [Cron is not a shell script](http://www.alleft.com/sysadmin/common-cron-mistakes/#It’s+not+a+shell+script) and you can't do everything you can do in one, like dereferencing variables or setting arbitrary new variables.

I suggest you replace your values into the cron line and avoid usage of variables

```
/usr/bin/php5.6 /home/michael/bash/checkalive.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Also, consider removing the trailing `&` as it is not necessary.

Comment: I had found the problem. Thank you for your leads.